# What is the difference between the 'set' operation using loc vs iloc?

Tags: pandas

What is the difference between the 'set' operation using loc vs iloc?

```
df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('ColName')] = 3
#vs#
df.loc[2, 'ColName'] = 3
```

Why does the website of iloc (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) not have any set examples like those shown in loc website (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)? Is loc the preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much of a difference to say. It all comes down to your need and requirement.

Say you have label of the index and column name (most of the time) you are supposed to use  `loc` (location) operator to assign the values.

Whereas like in normal matrix, you usually are going to have only the index number of the row and column and hence the cell location via integers (for `i`) your are supposed to use `iloc` (integer based location) for assignment.

Pandas DataFrame support indexing via both usual integer based and index based.

The problem arise when the index (the row or column) is itself integer instead of some string. So to make a clear difference to what operation user want to perform using integer based or label based indexing the two operations is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Main difference is `iloc` set values by position, `loc` by label.

Here are some alternatives:

**Sample**:

1. Not default index (if exist label 2 is overwritten cell, else appended new row with label):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=['A','B','C'], index=[2,1,8])
print (df)
   A  B  C
2  2  2  6
1  1  3  9
8  6  1  0

df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('A')] = 30
print (df)
    A  B  C
2   2  2  6
1   1  3  9
8  30  1  0
```

Appended new row with `0`:

```
df.loc[0, 'A'] = 70

print (df)
      A    B    C
a   2.0  2.0  6.0
b   1.0  3.0  9.0
c  30.0  1.0  0.0
0  70.0  NaN  NaN
```

Overwritten label `2`:

```
df.loc[2, 'A'] = 50
print (df)
    A  B  C
2  50  2  6
1   1  3  9
8  30  1  0
```

2. Default index (working same, because 3rd index has label 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=['A','B','C'])
print (df)

df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('A')] = 30
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   2  2  6
1   1  3  9
2  30  1  0

df.loc[2, 'A'] = 50

print (df)
    A  B  C
0   2  2  6
1   1  3  9
2  50  1  0
```

3. Not integer index - (working for set by position, for select by label is appended new row):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=['A','B','C'], index=list('abc'))
print (df)

df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('A')] = 30
print (df)
    A  B  C
a   2  2  6
b   1  3  9
c  30  1  0

df.loc[2, 'A'] = 50

print (df)
      A    B    C
a   2.0  2.0  6.0
b   1.0  3.0  9.0
c  30.0  1.0  0.0
2  50.0  NaN  NaN
```